# Full-text catalog timeout, SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql, full-text-search, tsql

we are re-loading a db with new data using backup/restore process. Once restore is complete, we re-build the full-text catalog. Full text searches work, no timeouts for about a day or so. However if the search hasn't been used for a day, two days, the searches timeout. If I were to re-build a catalog when timeouts occur, everything works. It also works if a user does any search at least once a day.

I can set to re-populate catalog once a day (early in the morning let's say.) However, is this the right approach? It would cover up the issue, but what's the cause of it? We're using SQL Server 2005 and Win Server 2003 and search is done through web interface.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the fix described in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915850) did the trick.

```
sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0;
GO
```

Even though it says this is only a problem for servers not connected to the Internet, we found that it could effect servers with weird Internet connection setups.